# raise TypeError('The added layer must be ' TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to know what is it that I am doing wrong here.

imports:

```
import glob
import rasterio as rs
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as kr
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Accuracy, accuracy
```

The code that worked:

```
model = kr.Sequential([
    kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=(10,10,8)), # output is a 9x9x32 image
    kr.layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu'),                        # output is a 6x6x64 image
    kr.layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3),                                           # output is a 2x2x64 image
    kr.layers.Conv2D(1024, (2,2), activation='relu'),                      # output is a 1x1x1024 layer
    kr.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    kr.layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.softmax)
]) 

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=50) 
print("results=",model.evaluate(test, test_labels))
```

The code throwing an error:

```
in_shape = (10,10,8)

conv1 = kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=in_shape)(train)
print('shape of 2nd convolution', np.array(conv1).shape)

conv2 = kr.layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu')(conv1)
print('shape of 2nd convolution', np.array(conv2).shape)

pool1 = kr.layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3))(conv2)
print('shape of 1st pool', np.array(pool1).shape)

conv3 = kr.layers.Conv2D(1024, (2,2), activation='relu')(pool1)
print('shape of 3rd convolution', np.array(conv3).shape)

conv4 = kr.layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.softmax)(conv3)
print('shape of 4th convolution', np.array(conv4).shape)

# M   O   D   E   L

model = kr.Sequential([conv1, conv2, pool1, conv3, conv4])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=50) 
print("results=",model.evaluate(test, test_labels))
```

The error:

> TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: tf.Tensor

Comment: Your second code makes no sense, you somehow mix the use of the functional and sequential APIs which is not supported, this is not how you use the functional API either.

Comment: When you pass an input to a layer like this: `pool1 = kr.layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3))(conv2)`, which you have passed `(conv2)`, the result will be a tensor. If you want just layers, simply remove each input after layers definition.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are mixing [Keras Sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) with [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Briefly, when you do this:

```py
foo = kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=in_shape)(train)
```

because you are using the layer on a specified value (that is `train`), the result stored in `foo` will be a Tensor, as specified [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#returns):

> A tensor of rank 4+ representing activation(conv2d(inputs, kernel) + bias).

This is indeed the typical way when you try to create a model using the Functional API.

However, as the error you get suggests:

> The added layer must be an instance of Layer class. Found: tf.Tensor

a Keras Sequential model accepts something of `Layer`  class. The problem is that when you do this:

```py
model = kr.Sequential([conv1, conv2, pool1, conv3, conv4])
```

you are adding to the Sequential model a series of Tensors.

On the contrary, what you want to add to the Sequential model is a variable storing the Layer, so you should do this:

```py
foo = kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation="relu", input_shape=in_shape)
[...]
model = kr.Sequential([foo, ...])
```

note that there is no `train` at the end of the `kr.layers.Conv2D` layer, and the `foo` variable is actually storing the Layer,

or this:

```py
model = kr.Sequential()
model.add(kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation="relu", input_shape=in_shape))
[...]
```

The other piece of code you posted is actually working because you are indeed adding directly the Layer to the sequential model:

```py
model = kr.Sequential([
    kr.layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=(10,10,8)), # output is a 9x9x32 image
    kr.layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu'),                        # output is a 6x6x64 image
    kr.layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3),                                           # output is a 2x2x64 image
    kr.layers.Conv2D(1024, (2,2), activation='relu'),                      # output is a 1x1x1024 layer
    kr.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    kr.layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was able to solve the problem and have posted the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct myself with the help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAhPiF3yiXI, what I wanted to do was to implement **functional api** in **keras** and the equivalent code for the same is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inp = layers.Input(shape=(10,10,8))

conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32, (2,2), activation='relu')(inp)
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu')(conv1)
pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3)(conv2)
conv3 = layers.Conv2D(1024, (2,2), activation='relu')(pool1)
dr_out = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv3)

out = layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), activation='softmax')(dr_out)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```